# Check call_user_func_array return data PHP

Tags: php

How to check call_user_func_array return data PHP:

i have class 1:

```
class MyClass
{
   public function show()
   {
      echo 'This is show function';
   }
}
```

class 2:

```
class MyClass2
{
   public function show2()
   {
      return 'This is show2 function';
   }
}
```

now, i check:

```
if(isset(call_user_func_array(array(new MyClass,'show'),$params)))
{
   echo 'Has return data';
}
else
{
   call_user_func_array(array(new MyClass,'show'),$params);//run normal function
}

if(isset(call_user_func_array(array(new MyClass2,'show2'),$params)))
{
   echo 'Has return data';
}
else
{
   call_user_func_array(array(new MyClass2,'show2'),$params);//run normal function
}
```

but not working, somebody can help me?

Comment: What are you trying to check?  Are you looking for `method_exists()` instead?

Comment: I want to check if the function can return, I will not call call_user_func_array, if there is no return, then I will echo the call to call_user_func_array text as in the example.

Comment: You want to know if the function returns a value? What kind of values do you want to check for? Boolean? String? Null? Array?

Comment: What is *not working*? Do you get an error? Does it echo the wrong thing?  And you're calling the function twice.  If it echos, it will echo twice...

Comment: Don't use `isset()` for these checks. You just want to verify that *a value is returned*, not that *a variable is set*.

Answer (score 0):

Warning
isset() only works with variables as passing anything else will result in a parse error. For checking if constants are set use the defined() function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php